# Shared modules and typescript aliases using firebase functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having trouble getting my shared typescript library to work using an alias path with Firebase Functions.

The code compiles if I reference it using relative paths, but my `functions/` directory uploads to Firebase Functions and can't use relative files outside of its directory.

#### Directory Structure

```sh
functions/
- tsconfig.json
- src/*.ts
- lib/*.js

shared/
- tsconfig.json
- src/*.ts
- lib/*.ts

src/
- components/*.vue

tsconfig.json
tsconfig-base.json
```

In my function file, I try and reference one of my shared modules like so:

```js
import { MyClass } from '@shared/src/MyClass'; // Error: Cannot find module '@shared/src/MyClass'

import { MyClass } from '../../shared/src/MyClass' // This Compiles, but fails deploying Cloud Functions
```

Because Cloud Functions needs to have all dependencies within the `functions` directory, I'm unable to deploy the functions, even though it all compiles using relative paths.

What am I doing wrong with my setup, structure, or deployment?

I've also tried adding `"@shared": "file:../shared"` to `functions/package.json` as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies)

#### tsconfig-base.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2018"
        ],
        "target": "es2018",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "files": [],
    "include": [],
    "exclude": [
        "lib",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

#### shared/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "references": [],
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

### functions/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../shared"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": [
        "../shared/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in cloud functions, but if you need to have all dependencies in the `functions/` folder it seems to me this will not work, even if you can setup the path mapping, since the files are still physically outside. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: "paths" should be in compiler options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250213/typescript-import-returns-cannot-find-module/61250662#61250662 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38006

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL. - it fixed the local compiling issue, but still fails to compile with Firebase Emulator and fails to deploy

Comment: All of the code needed at runtime will have to be in either the functions folder or node_modules.  If the latter, your package.json will need to be able to identify it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ayyappa just added a brief summary of my workaround as an answer

Comment: Would it be possible to solve this with workspaces?

Answer (score 2):

My current workaround for anyone interested is to use webpack (or `vue.config.js` in my case) to copy shared files into the `functions` directory, and add `functions/shared` to my `.gitignore`.

Not the best approach, but it works.

Comment: Hitting the same pain and likely will resolve the same way.